# I own canon powershot camera A150. It seems the AA bateries I put in it won't seem to power it, what batteries does it need?

Tags: canon, battery

I own a Canon Power shot A 150 camera and every time I load AA batteries now, they don't seem to power the camera anymore. I was thinking it was the batteries, but maybe they're the wrong type of batteries. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Do you mean the Canon PowerShot SX150, or the Fuji FinePix A150....? I don't believe Canon has an A150.... Regardless, what does the manual say are the required batteries?

Comment: Check if the contacts in camera have corrosion on them.

Comment: Check that the batteries are polarised correctly. If you are using rechargeable batteries, make sure they are fully charged.

Comment: Are you talking about [a Powershot A510](https://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canona510)? Are you using Alkaline or NiMh rechargeable AAs?